# iOS application Ad Hoc installation stuck due to wrong configuration

Tags: ios, installation, ad-hoc-distribution

My application got stuck on installation due to wrong configuration on my iPhone with iOS 7. Provisioning profiles, certificates, devices everything seems ok.

I found an example of how to prepare a web page to provide a download link for your iOS application. I completed the necessary steps with one small mistake. The mistake was my appName.ipa and appName.plist was different.

As a result, the link was look like working but was installing 2 apps because of this difference. Real app finished installing but other clone that comes from the wrong .plis file never finished installing.

I'm able to install/remove application but this second clone cannot be removed even there is an (X) symbol in edit mode. When I press the (X) symbol for deleting it shows the Alert View but not deleting the clone even I press Delete or Cancel.

I tried to delete it but couldn't find a way. I currently don't have any issues installing/removing my application but it just stuck there. Is there anyone has the same problem before or any ideas?

[image: This is a sample screenshot how is it look like]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realised the problem, it's about the Bundle Identifier difference. I created a new app with the ghost icon's bundle identifier and run it from XCode, so XCode overrode it and successfully installed the test app.

Comment: Happy you've found the solution ! I give you +1 as this can help others !

Answer (score 1):

Did you try with [iPhone Configuration utility (Win)](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1466)  / [iPhone Configuration Utility (Mac)](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1465) ?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I didn't know these utilities, however they didn't solve my problem. This hang installation didn't appear in the applications list.

Comment: Did you try the proposed solution when googling for "ios 7 ghost icon" ?

Comment: Thank you Armand DOHM, your answers didn't help me to solve the problem. They are helpful but the issue was they are not finding the ghost icon. I found the reason why this ghost icon appears and put the solution as answer to this question.